# Configuration of EasyPhp wamp

Tags: configuration, easyphp

I am using EasyPhp (easyphp.org)

When I list a directory I can only see the filename with a limited number of characters.

- ThisIsAnExample.php
- AndThisIsALongerExampl..>

[image: ScreenCapture]

I managed to expand the with of the table containing the FileName column but the long names are still croped.

Is there a configuration to allow more characters in the FileName?

Comment: Can you show the code you used to achieve this? It is very hard to tell why this is happening without more information

Comment: Hum. There is no code to show. I only expanded the table width ading some css in the header.html file. But the char limit is exactly the same.

Comment: I am not familiar with the interface for EasyPHP but it sounds like they've set `text-overflow:ellipses;` in the CSS or it is being programmatically truncated on the server-side. Unless you dig deep into the source code, I would imagine you are stuck with this functionality.

Comment: Actually as it is a wamp I have access to the source files. I can't modifie the binaries but there is a bunch of php files. I have the feeling there is one I can modify. I will explore the text-overflow tag. But as it adds some "..>" characters. I don't think it is just css. :o)

Comment: You are probably correct. If you are using a modern web browser then you can right-click and inspect the element to view the CSS properties applied to the container. This will tell you right away if the ellipses is being applied with CSS or not. Good luck!

Comment: Confirmed. No ellipses are added to the element. The server itself is sending the filename croped. u_u

Comment: In all honesty, you seem like a person that is too advanced to be using EasyPHP. May I ask why you have chosen to use it rather than downloading and installing Apache, PHP, and MySQL as separate applications?

Comment: Lol. I am wondering that too. You are right. I will instal them that way. XoD. But the answer is I am a designer, not a programer, so it distracts me less using easyphp.